# Dynamic height for same content in UITabelviewcell using autolayout programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am creating custom UITableViewCell and adding constraints programatically. But my same text not adjusting with in label and that resulting in different height for random cell. I have looked in to various tutorial and visited answers on other stack questions but not able to solve my problem.

As per my understanding this is the issue of priority between left and right label. I have also added this line while setting constraint.

```
[righSideLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:950 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Comment: Don't post a link to the project. Instead, update your question with just the code relevant to the issue.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    
}

Comment: plese add this two methods in your .m file

Comment: did you try to return the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @rmaddy code is in multiple class i will try to add

Comment: @pradipkikani  tried with your answer not worked also already added
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; this line of code.

Comment: please add <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> in .h file

Comment: @pradipkikani suggest you to download sample zip code already did all these things

Answer (score -1):

You can set the **rowHeight** property to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** and put the constraint on the Label of your Cell and set the estimatedRowHeight and don't use **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method.**Remember** try to put top,bottom,leading and trailing Constraints.